# Word VBA returns false positive with .find.found

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, find

I have created a Word macro to locate close repetition of words and it reports finding matches when the search term is a portion of another word in the search range.

For example, in a document that consists of the sentence

This is one clause, and this isn't another.

The macro highlights the repetition of "this" correctly but also highlights "is" because it shows up as part of "isn't."

The code, below, takes a word, searches for it in the next n words (using MatchWholeWord = true) and highlights any appearances. It then checks to see if anything was found and highlights the search term if there was. This second process appears to be where the bug is, but I cannot come up with an alternate process for verifying the search was successful.

(This macro has been simplified to the most basic functions; the full version, for example, screens out frequent words before running a search.)

```
Sub FindCloseRepetitionDebug()

    Dim rAllContent As Range
    Dim rLastSetWord As Range
    Dim rLastSearchWord As Range
    Dim rSearchSet As Range
    Dim sCurrentWord As String
    Dim iLengthAllContent As Long
    Dim iComparisonLength As Integer
    Dim rCurrentSet As Range
    
    iComparisonLength = 10
     
    Set rAllContent = Selection.Range
    rAllContent.WholeStory

    iLengthAllContent = rAllContent.Words.Count
    Set rLastSetWord = rAllContent.Words(iLengthAllContent)
    If iLengthAllContent < iComparisonLength Then iComparisonLength = iLengthAllContent

    Set rCurrentSet = rAllContent.Words(1)
    rCurrentSet.SetRange Start:=rAllContent.Words(1).Start, End:=rAllContent.Words(iComparisonLength).End
 
    Do
        sCurrentWord = Trim(rCurrentSet.Words(1).Text)
        Set rSearchSet = rCurrentSet.Words(1)
        rSearchSet.SetRange Start:=rCurrentSet.Words(2).Start, End:=rCurrentSet.Words(iComparisonLength).End
        If Len(sCurrentWord) > 1 Then
            With rSearchSet.Find
                With .Replacement
                    .Highlight = True
                End With
                .Execute Forward:=True, MatchWholeWord:=True, FindText:=sCurrentWord, Replace:=wdReplaceAll, ReplaceWith:="", Format:=True
                If .Found = True Then rCurrentSet.Words(1).HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
            End With
        End If
        Set rLastSearchWord = rCurrentSet.Words(iComparisonLength)
        If rLastSearchWord.IsEqual(Range:=rLastSetWord) = False Then
            rCurrentSet.MoveStart Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
            rCurrentSet.MoveEnd Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
        ElseIf rCurrentSet.IsEqual(Range:=rLastSetWord) = False Then
            rCurrentSet.MoveStart Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
            If iComparisonLength > 2 Then
                iComparisonLength = iComparisonLength - 1
                ElseIf sCurrentWord = rLastSetWord.Text Then
                    rCurrentSet.MoveStart Unit:=wdWord, Count:=-1
                    rCurrentSet.HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
                    Exit Do
                Else: Exit Do
            End If
            Else: Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Is *"searches for it in the next n words"* the n ie. 10 (*iComparisonLength = 10*)  in your code? Do you mean to find repetitive words in the range of 10( or *iComparisonLength*) words?

Comment: If that's then you can try the *Find all Repetition Words in n words* code in my updated answer.

Comment: `ReplaceWith:=""` will clear all the `FindText:=sCurrentWord` in your find range! Are you sure? As soon as they are cleared and all the `.Highlight = True` setting will be meanless.

Comment: @oscar The code ReplaceWith:="" is standard for replacing formatting instead of text. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/finding-and-replacing-text-or-formatting

Answer (score 1):

`Find.Found` can be unreliable. Fortunately, it is not necessary to use it as `Find.Excecute` is a function that returns a Boolean. So, you can try using:

```
        If .Execute(Forward:=True, MatchWholeWord:=True, FindText:=sCurrentWord, Replace:=wdReplaceAll, ReplaceWith:="", Format:=True) Then
            rCurrentSet.Words(1).HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
        End If
```

Comment: Timothy - I've substituted this code, but I still get the same results. I can play with the find parameters and see if one of them is inadvertently broadening the scope of the search.

Comment: I made the following change  based on your code and it appears to solve the issue: 

If .Execute = True Then rCurrentSet.Words(1).HighlightColorIndex = iHighlight

Comment: @MichaelSchuler *it appears to solve the issue:*, so all done? If indeed, I won't try it then. You still can consider my solution it seems got a better performance.

Comment: @oscar Thanks for your proposal. My question was specifically about .find.found identifying false positives, rather than looking for completely different code. Your version runs faster on short documents but much slower on the book-length documents I work with (23 seconds versus 33 seconds for a 5,000-word document but 22 minutes, 48 seconds versus 8 minutes, 23 seconds for a 70,000 word document).

Comment: Any solution that uses the `Words` collection will be inefficient on long documents. Even worse, it will likely be inaccurate because what VBA identifies as a word won’t always be the same as what a human would recognise as a word.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find duplicate words in a document, you can try my solution. See how it compares to your performance. If it works, you may want to use mine instead. I will come back later to see where the problem is with your method.
You can also extract those duplicate info from my code if you need or want.

### Find all Repetition Words in a document

```vb
Sub FindCloseRepetitionWord()
    Dim ws As Word.Words, w As Range, wx As String, i As Long, key, cln As New VBA.Collection, ur As UndoRecord
    'Dim dictCtr As New Scripting.Dictionary, dictW As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dictCtr As Object, dictW As Object
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "FindCloseRepetitionWord"
    
    Set dictCtr = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictW = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set ws = ActiveDocument.Words
    For Each w In ws
        wx = VBA.StrConv(VBA.Trim(w.Text), vbLowerCase)
        If InStr(Chr(13) + ",.;:?!'""-~/\", wx) = 0 Then
            If dictCtr.Count > 0 And dictCtr.Exists(wx) Then
                i = dictCtr(wx)
                If dictW.Exists(wx) Then Set cln = dictW(wx)
            End If
            dictCtr(wx) = i + 1
            cln.Add w
            Set dictW(wx) = cln
            i = 0
            Set cln = Nothing
        End If
    Next w
    
    For Each key In dictCtr.Keys
        If dictCtr(key) > 1 Then
            For Each w In dictW(key)
                If VBA.Right(w, 1) = " " Then w.End = w.End - 1
                w.HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
            Next w
        End If
    Next key
    
    ur.EndCustomRecord
End Sub
```

### Find all Repetition Words in n words

```vb
Sub FindCloseRepetitionWordn()
    Dim ws As Word.Words, w As Range, wx As String, i As Long, key, cln As New VBA.Collection, ur As UndoRecord, rng As Range, d As Document
'    Dim dictCtr As New Scripting.Dictionary, dictW As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim dictCtr As Object, dictW As Object
    
    Dim iComparisonLength As Integer, n As Integer
    
    iComparisonLength = 10
    n = iComparisonLength
    
    Set ur = Word.Application.UndoRecord
    ur.StartCustomRecord "FindCloseRepetitionWord"
    
    Set d = ActiveDocument
    Set dictCtr = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictW = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set ws = d.Words
    For Each w In ws
        wx = VBA.StrConv(VBA.Trim(w.Text), vbLowerCase)
        If InStr(Chr(13) + ",.;:?!'""-~/\", wx) = 0 Then
            If dictCtr.Count > 0 And dictCtr.Exists(wx) Then
                i = dictCtr(wx)
                If dictW.Exists(wx) Then Set cln = dictW(wx)
            End If
            dictCtr(wx) = i + 1
            cln.Add w
            Set dictW(wx) = cln
            i = 0
            Set cln = Nothing
        End If
    Next w
    
    Set rng = d.Range
    For Each key In dictCtr.Keys
        If dictCtr(key) > 1 Then
            Set cln = dictW(key)
            For i = 1 To cln.Count - 1
                rng.SetRange cln.Item(i).Start, cln.Item(i + 1).End
                If rng.Words.Count <= n Then
                    Set w = cln.Item(i)
                    If VBA.Right(w, 1) = " " Then w.End = w.End - 1
                    w.HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
                    Set w = cln.Item(i + 1)
                    If VBA.Right(w, 1) = " " Then w.End = w.End - 1
                    w.HighlightColorIndex = wdTurquoise
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next key
    
    ur.EndCustomRecord
End Sub
```

Comment: Oscar - This works for identifying any repetition, but I'm only looking for repetition within n words of an appearance of a word.

Comment: @MichaelSchuler *within n words of an appearance of a word.*, I don't understand this. did you mean you have a specified amount of words (word list?) and you want to see how these words are repeated in the document? If this is, then just give the list of words to this code and put a condition to determine what you want and what not, that's it. In this code you also can print out the counting result in a new document by using the **dictCtr** to show it.